# How to copy a String substring to a StringBuilder

Tags: java, performance, java-8

What is the fastest way to copy a string substring to a StringBuilder?
I tried:

- `builder.append(string.substring(start, end))` but it uses two array copies.
- `builder.append(string, start, end)` but it uses an for loop instead of array copy

Sadly `StringBuilder#getValue` is package private so i can not use it in `String#getChars`.
Also, StringBuilder is final what means I can not change the getValue access or add a `append(str, start, end)` method that would use `String#getChars` instead of a for-loop.

I think I'm missing something. I mean I can not be the first one who wants this feature.

**Update:**

As @Slaw stated StringBuilder#append(CharSequence, int, int) was changed to use arraycopy instead of a for-loop somewere between 9 and 13. I am happy this 'issue' got fixed.

Comment: Why do you care? Do you have a use case which goes from O(n) to O(n^2) or similar?

Comment: Perhaps the implementation has changed from whatever version you're looking at, but currently `StringBuilder#append(CharSequence,int,int)` attempts to use `arraycopy` when the first argument is an instance of `Sting`. See https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#L1752

Comment: That is really interesting @Slaw in OpenJDK 8 this was different

Comment: I'm still curious why you care this much about string buffer performance.

Answer (score 2):

use can use constructor of the StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(string.substring(start, end));
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good solution. However that would defeat the purpose of StringBuilder in my particular case.

Comment: In which regard does this differ from the `append(string.substring(start, end))` already shown in the question?

Answer (score 0):

`String` implements `CharSequence`, so you can use `StringBuffer.append(CharSequence s,int start, int end)`, however I would caution that unless you know that this is likely to be/is a problem, then using this method instead of `substring` is premature optimization.

Comment: I listed this approach in "thinks I tried". Sadly it uses a for loop instead of arraycopy as CharSequence does not provide getChars()

Comment: @David what do you think, does `arraycopy` do internally?

Comment: I mean to be fair arraycopy is probably vectorized/faster, while in my experience jvm autovectorization is pretty trash for anything other than ultra simple loops(though I guess this counts as an ultra simple loop). Why @David cares so much about string buffer performance however, is still a mystery to me.

Comment: I am writing a parser for a very uncommon file type. In the application start 1GB of this text gets parsed. I thought maybe I could improve performance this way.

Comment: Arraycopy should be faster i mean it only copys references so it may acutally just copy the memory section right? I dont really now mutch about jvm natives but I saw on github that some large projects only use arraycopy if the array is larger than 8 so maybe it is not always faster.

Comment: So you should always profile before doing this kind of detailed optimization. For example you need to know that you are not memory bandwith bound. If you determine that you absolutely do need arraycopy, I would probably use raw char arrays/arraylists